# How to delete specyfic chars in string by an index - pandas df

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Names` column in `df` table :

```
Names
ARTBAT0043243232r0
ARTBAF005401241740
BTNKLA012325122540
KOPLFT087656754440
```

**expected result**
I need to delete first 3 chars and 6th. So an example in the first row should be:
`ARTBAT0043243232r0` -> `BA0043243232r0` etc.

I have read post on SO, but I found nothing helping in my case. I can do it by for but I prefer to use pandas method coz file has 4 millions of records.

My attempt:

first deleting 3 fist chars:

```
df1['Names'].str[3:18]
```

Then try to replace 6th to empty:

```
df1['Names'].replace(df1['Names'].str[6], '')
```

But I run it 40 min ago and it's still working (so I even don't know it's working, may throw an error). Maybe is a better way to delete or replace it faster?

Most posts on SO handling with deleting a string of chars, not a:b and g. But it's possible that I missed some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`series.str.slice_replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice_replace.html):

```
df.Names.str[3:].str.slice_replace(2,3,'')
```

---

```
0    BA0043243232r0
1    BA005401241740
2    KL012325122540
3    LF087656754440
Name: Names, dtype: object
```